# Bind event made in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, bind

Hello guys i made this event for know when press the button enter but if i try to use bind or on it doesn't work. any help please?

this is my event:

```
$.fn.enterKey = function (fnc) {
    return this.each(function () {
        $(this).keypress(function (ev) {
            var keycode = (ev.keyCode ? ev.keyCode : ev.which);
            if (keycode == '13') {
                fnc.call(this, ev);
            }
        })
    })
}
```

if i try to do:

```
    $('.foo').on('enterKey', function() {
    // other code --> doesn't work
    });

    $('.foo').bind('enterKey', function() {
    // other code --> doesn't work
    });
```

this is my code:

```
var add_comment = { // add comment
    urlRemove : CI_ROOT + 'add_comment_team/',
    run : function() {
        add_comment.share('.comment');
    },
    share : function(obj) {
        var alreadySent = false;
        $(obj).enterKey(function() {
            var comment = $(this);
            if (comment.val() != "") {
                if(!alreadySent) {
                     alreadySent = true; 
                     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  add_comment.urlRemove,
                        data: "text=" + comment.val() + "&post_id=" + comment.attr('id'),
                        success: function(html) {
                            comment.val('');
                            comment.closest('.shared_box').children('.recent_comment').append(html);
                            alreadySent = false;
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error on ajax call');
                            alreadySent = false;
                        }
                    }); 
                } 
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }); 
    }

};
```

i tried to do like that with the trigger but still doesn't work

```
var add_comment = { // add comment
    urlRemove : CI_ROOT + 'add_comment_team/',
    run : function() {
        add_comment.share('.comment');
    },
    share : function(obj) {
        var alreadySent = false;
        $(document).on('enterKey',obj, function() {
            var comment = $(this);
            if (comment.val() != "") {
                if(!alreadySent) {
                     alreadySent = true; 
                     $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:  add_comment.urlRemove,
                        data: "text=" + comment.val() + "&post_id=" + comment.attr('id'),
                        success: function(html) {
                            comment.val('');
                            comment.closest('.shared_box').children('.recent_comment').append(html);
                            alreadySent = false;
                        },
                        error: function(){
                            alert('Error on ajax call');
                            alreadySent = false;
                        }
                    }); 
                } 
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        });

        $(obj).trigger('enterKey');

    }

};
```

Comment: It doesn't work because you didn't create an event, you just created a method. If you want to create a custom event, then read this article http://www.sitepoint.com/jquery-custom-events/

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa Thank you, i'm reading this article i think it's right your answer, but i'm not very good with Jquery and i have some issue to understand that, can you do a example? Cheese

Comment: The article already has an example.

Comment: Yes, i saw it but i can't understand because the examples are with functions, in my case is about method.

Answer (score 0):

```
 $('.foo').enterKey();
```

You haven't made any events,You have just added a method called `enterkey` to the **jQuery.prototype**

`$.fn` points to the **jQuery.prototype**. Any methods or properties you add to it become available to all instance of the jQuery wrapped objects.So,it should work.

Make sure you trigger it properly.

Comment: Yes i know, it work like that but if i make the element .foo by jquery it doesn't work with that event. Thank you so much

Comment: When are you trigerring this ?

Comment: Use a delegated event handler in your function to handle dynamic elements.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how can i do that?

Comment: @fabrizio:he is talking about on and trigger!!

Comment: @OPUS ok thank you, i update my post with more datails please check out where is my mistake thank you very much.

Comment: The user asked how to trigger an event, not how to call a method.

Comment: @AurelioDeRosa:the user assumed something terribly wrong that had to be corrected.Besides,he posted entire code as an update,This question had a fiff meaning before update ..now its looking completely different.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this one:

```
$(document).on('enterKey', '.foo', function() {
   // other code --> might work
});
```

Delegate the event to the document or the closest static parent.

#### From the docs:

> When we define a custom event type using the .on() method, the second argument to .trigger() can become useful.

[.trigger() documentation @ jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

or you can add a `.trigger()` method:

```
$('.foo').trigger('enterkey');
```

Comment: Thank you but this method doesn't work, where can i put the trigger event?

Comment: i tried to add the trigger on my function but doesn't work maybe i'm doing mistake in some place

Comment: How the user can trigger an event if it declared a method instead?